# How many elements are in this group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, functions

Let $\mathcal{Sym}(\mathbb{R})$ be a group with the composition ($(f \circ g) (x) = f(g(x))$ as its operator and $\mathcal{Sym}(\mathbb{R})$ := $\{ f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R} \ | \ f \ \text{is bijective} \}$

Show that every subgroup of $\mathcal{Sym}(\mathbb{R})$ that contains the function $x \mapsto x^3$ has an infinite amount of elements.

Find a subgroup of $\mathcal{Sym}(\mathbb{R})$ with 4 elements.

How does one start here? I am clueless.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints:

For the first part, you are basically looking to show that as long as the function $f(x)=x^3$ is in your group of functions (under composition), then infinitely many such functions are. Can you find any other function that must be in any subgroup that contains $f(x)=x^3$? Think of this as "the subgroup that $f(x)=x^3$ generates."

For the second part, you're looking for a group with $4$ elements. It must be a subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb R)$, but we'll deal with that later. What groups with four elements do you know? What would it mean for such a group to be a subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb R)$? Say you have some function $f\in\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb R)$. Using what you learned in the previous part, when would it generate a finite group?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part consider the powers $f^n$ of the given map. Powers mean composition with itself.

For the second part consider the function which send $1 \rightarrow 2 , 2\rightarrow 3, 3\rightarrow 4, 4\rightarrow 1$ and fixes rest of the elements. Take the cyclic group generated by this function.